# Filtering Lines of a CSV file. I want to skip a certain amount of lines based on a variable

Tags: java, groovy

I have the following programm:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDate

def firstLine = this.args[4]
def filteredOutput
String file = this.args[0]
String outputFile = file + "_filtered.csv"
def pathInput = "../input/" + file
def pathOutput = "../output/" + outputFile
String td = this.args[1]
def keyField = this.args[2]
def path = this.args[3]
final FMT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('dd.MM.yyyy')


def lineCounter = 0

//Integer.parseInt(keyField)
//println keyField

def targetDate = LocalDate.parse(td, FMT)

def test = new File(pathInput)
def filtered = new File(pathOutput)
filteredOutput = filtered.newPrintWriter()


if (firstLine>lineCounter) {
    lineCounter = lineCounter +1
}

else {
    test.filterLine(filteredOutput) { line ->
   def parts = line.split(';')
   def lineDate = LocalDate.parse(parts[Integer.parseInt(keyField)], FMT)
   lineDate >= targetDate
}


}

println pathInput
println pathOutput
```

It reads a CSV File and deletes all rows which have a earlier date then the one I give in an argument.
The files I read have a header row tho in which the column names are in.
I want to start the filtering in the second row or better based on a variable to be more flexibel. As you can see I tried to catch this case with an if else and count up to the rows i want to skip but that didn't exactly go as i planned it in my head :D

Is this possible with my current code?

Comment: "_I found the solution._" - I am glad you found a solution. Instead of writing a note in the question, you can [provide a full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) as an actual answer. Doing this will make it easier for future visitors to see that the problem has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Instead of parsing my targetDate I deleted that step. As I want rows without date to be replicated 1:1 in the new file this is better. Rows with dates get checked and removed, while rows without a date will stay the same.